# Can zyprexa cause thinning of brain cortex

Tags: medications, antipsychotic

Aka olanzapine. It’s a commonly prescribed anti psychotic, I’ve seen written in a couple of places that it thins brain cortex ……..

Comment: Psychology & Neuroscience.SE would be a better site for this question.